# How to obtain values of Confidence Interval limits in Python

Tags: python, seaborn, confidence-interval

I have a seaborn.regplot plot of urban fraction and urban heat island intensity showing each individual point in a scatter plot and the regression line with a 95% confidence interval. Is there anyway to obtain an array or list of the UHI intensity at the upper and lower limits of the 95% confidence interval?

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

figure, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set(xlim=(0, 100))
ax.text(70, 2.3, "r = %s"%(np.round(correlation, decimals=2)))
ax.text(70, 2.15, "p = %s"%(np.round(p_value, decimals=2)))
x, y = pd.Series(urban_fraction, name="Urban Fraction (%)"), pd.Series(Spring_Max, name='UHI Intensity ($^\circ$C)')
ax = sns.regplot(x=x, y=y, ci=95, marker="+")
```

[image: seaborn.regplot plot with confidence interval of 95%]

Comment: seaborn.regplot only returns the `matplotlib.Axes` object that it uses. So you're going to need to dig into the source code of seaborn to see how the CIs are computed under the hood.

Comment: Or, use a statistical library if you want to obtain statistics.